# Not receiving background fetch remote notifications while application is backgrounded, and user does not enter through push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, push-notification

My application currently uses the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` and `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` delegate methods to handle background remote notifications. Intermittently, a push notification will appear, and I will not receive a log that says that it has called either of my application delegate methods. I have tested for suspended, active, background, and suspended states, and they all seem to be working correctly. About 1 in every 30 pushes I get a 'dead' push notification.

****NOTE: This case only happens when I do NOT enter by touching the push notification, and happens unpredictably.**

Comment: If you app is completely unloaded (i.e. not suspended/in background) and the user relaunches from the icon (not the notification) then you will not receive the notification

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, I know I won't get the notification through the user dictionary, but since I have background fetch and remote notifications turned on, it should still hit application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler even when in background or suspended. If the application is unloaded by iOS, it should relaunch into a suspended state and handle the notification, correct?

Comment: Is your app in the background or unloaded?

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm seeing the error in both states

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error came from an iOS 8 "feature" in Apple's docs. If an iPhone has less than great cellular or wifi signal, low battery, or is not plugged into a charger, the phone will receive the notification on the lock screen, but will not launch the app into a suspended state. Therefore, background events such as `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` will not be fired IF you do not enter directly into the application by swiping the notification itself.

This was offset in testing by the fact that the device was always plugged into my development machine during debugging with a strong wifi signal, so I would never be put into a bad state.

This is extremely specific, but crucial if your app relies heavily on push notifications for background functionality.